# Add value to key in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap of my custom objects and each user should have many values. I figured out how to create the map and put one value to key but need help with a check like this (pseudo code):

```
If key exists then add another value to key

else add key and value
```

**I currently have:**

```
        Map<String, custom> map = new HashMap<String, custom>();


        for(customp : data) {
            map.put(p.getUser(), p);
        }
```

**Output:**

```
user1 / package.class@1231412
user2 / package.class@12fwf3
user3 / package.class@dc238d
```

**Code to get output:**

```
        for (Map.Entry<String, custom> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " / " + entry.getValue());
        }
```

**Need:**

```
user1 / package.custom@1231412, package.custom@vfee, package.custom@2riopj
user2 / package.custom@12fwf3, package.custom@cwfc3
user3 / package.custom@324rrf, package.custom@23d, package.custom@cvewff2
```

I will eventually be iterating over the map to get each object and use them but right now the key keeps replacing itself so I do not have all of my information.

Comment: You can use containsKey to check the value present or not.

Comment: You really should look at [Guava `Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have to use a `Map<String, List<custom>>` instead.

For each key, check if a mapping already exists, if it's the case add the custom to the list mapped with this key, otherwise create a new mapping and add it.

```
for(custom p : data) {
   List<custom> l = map.get(p.getUser());
   if(l == null){
       l = new ArrayList<>();
       map.put(p.getUser(), l);
   }
   l.add(p);
}
```

If you're using Java 8, the above logic can be simplified to this:

```
Map<String, List<custom>> map = data.stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(custom::getUser));
```

Finally if you're familiar with Guava librairies (and if you're not I recommend you too), look at the [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) class, it's a collection than can map each key to multiple values.

Also it's good to follow naming conventions.

Comment: So do you recommend I use a map with list<custom> values or a multimap with custom values

Comment: @JordanD I would recommend you to use a `Multimap`. However, if you want to only stick with the JDK and don't want to use additional librairies, use a `Map` with a `List<custom>`

Comment: I run into a different problem using `List<custom>` because in my for loop where I make my hashmap `data` is already a `List<custom>` so I get compiler errors: `for(custom p : data) {
    map.put(p.getUser(), p);
   }`

Comment: @JordanD But with this code for each `custom` in the list `data`, you are mapping its user with the `custom` object. This is not what you want I think.

Comment: I am putting it together slowly but surely, thank you for your patience and answers. I am testing it right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51121/discussion-between-jordand-and-zouzou)

Answer (score 2):

A `Map` can only contain one value for a key, not multiple. You have to use a `Map<String, List<Custom>>`, so the Map holds a List of values for one key.

Code for adding Values to a list inside the map:

```
Map<String, Custom> map = new HashMap<String, List<Custom>>();
for(Custom p : data) {
   List<Custom> list = map.get(p.getUser());
   if(list == null){
       list = new LinkedList<Custom>();
   }
   list.add(p);
   map.put(list);
}
```